# AzureFunctions binding to SendGrid

Tags: azure, sendgrid, azure-functions

Trying to figure out how to use SendGrid from an azure function. Not much docs to find, but this is what I've tried:

```
#r "SendGrid"
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using System;

public static void Run(string myQueueItem, out Mail message, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
    message=new Mail();
}
```

I've hardcoded to, from, subject and body, together with api key in the integrate output section. This is my function.json:

```
{
"bindings": [
{
  "name": "myQueueItem",
  "type": "queueTrigger",
  "direction": "in",
  "queueName": "send-email-request",
  "connection": "myStorage"
},
{
  "type": "sendGrid",
  "name": "message",
  "apiKey": "SG.xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "direction": "out",
  "to": "me@gmail.com",
  "from": "me@gmail.no",
  "subject": "hardcoded",
  "text": "test213"
}
],
"disabled": false
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Function ($SendEmailOnQueueTriggered) Error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.SendEmailOnQueueTriggered'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: 'SG.xxxxxx' does not resolve to a value.
Session Id: 9426f2d7e4374c7ba7e0612ea5dc1814
Timestamp: 2017-01-07T12:18:01.930Z
```

I've granted the Apikey full access in SendGrid. Any ideas what I've missed?

Larsi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ApiKey field is not the actual ApiKey, it should instead be the name of an AppSettings key defined in the "functions app settings".

Comment: Yes this trips people up alot. We do this for security purposes, to keep secret values out of your source code files. I've logged an issue in our repo here for us to improve the error message in these cases: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/965.

Answer (score 1):

Adding "AzureWebJobsSendGridApiKey" in your AppSettings via local.settings.json and in Configuration -> Application Setting via Azure Portal will work.